# Numpy Vectorize Signature

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

**Problem Statement**

I have to two arrays (`X` and `Y`) the of dimensions `(n,d)` and `(m,d)` respectively and want to apply a function to each row combination between the two matrices. The function that I want to apply is the following:

```
def norm(x, y):
    return np.linalg.norm(x-y)
```

Where `x` and `y` are the corresponding row vectors for the different matrices.
The output I am looking for is a matrix of shape `(n,m)` where each index is the norm of the difference between the corresponding row vectors in `X` and `Y`.

**Expected solution:**

Thus if the input matrices are:

```
X = [[1,1,1,1],
    [2,2,2,2]]

Y = [[3,3,3,3],
    [4,4,4,4]]
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
[[4,6],
[2,4]]
```

**Current Solution**

At this stage the only solution I've got is to use the `np.vectorize` function to vectorize my function and map the different rows to the function and get a matrix output. However when applying the following vectorization on the function:

```
norm_vec = np.vectorize(norm, signature='(d),(d)->()')
```

I get the following output:

```
[[4,4]]
```

It appears that the function is only mapping the function to each row pair and not every row combination.
I am still very new to the `vectorize` function and am not to sure how the `signature` argument works, but my gut tells me there is some way that this function with the proper signature will give me the right solution.

Is there someone that can maybe give me some further insight into how the `np.vectorize` function works and to build the correct `signature` to get the solution that I want, or point me in the right direction if I'm completely off track. I would like to avoid using for loops as I am planning to apply this function on some large matrices

Comment: Hey Armand, I dont see a Primiary Programming related question. FMPOV this question would have more chance to be answered when asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Venson, will post there as well.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `vectorize`? It doesn't improve speed. The signature feature is even slower.  It does not  avoid loops.  Read its disclaimers

Comment: `vectorize` uses `numpy` broadcasting, the same rules used with `arr1 + arr2`.  With the right mix of dimensions you can operate on pairs of rows.  But ....

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, I missed that part in the documentation. Do you perhaps have some other guidance as how I can approach the problem or is loops the best solution?

Comment: Hi @Venson : from our point of view at math.se, this question is essentially asking about documentation for a method in a particular programming language: no mathematics to it. In a case like this we would most likely (and did, in this case) point them to stackoverflow. Please bear it in mind next time: thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `signature` is ok; it just needs to use `broadcasting`:

```
In [374]: def norm(x, y): 
     ...:     return np.linalg.norm(x-y) 
     ...:                                                                                      

In [376]: f = np.vectorize(norm, signature='(d),(d)->()')                                      
In [377]:                                                                                      
In [377]: X = np.array([[1,1,1,1], 
     ...:     [2,2,2,2]]) 
     ...:  
     ...: Y = np.array([[3,3,3,3], 
     ...:     [4,4,4,4]])                                                                      
In [378]: f(X,Y)                                                                               
Out[378]: array([4., 4.])

In [379]: f(X[:,None,:], Y[None,:,:])                                                           
Out[379]: 
array([[4., 6.],
       [2., 4.]])
```

Your function first does `x-y`; so let's focus on that:

```
In [383]: f = np.vectorize(lambda x,y:x-y, signature='(d),(d)->(d)')                           
In [384]: f(X[:,None,:], Y[None,:,:])                                                           
Out[384]: 
array([[[-2, -2, -2, -2],
        [-3, -3, -3, -3]],

       [[-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-2, -2, -2, -2]]])
```

but we don't need `vectorize` to do this:

```
In [385]: X[:,None,:]-Y[None,:,:]                                                              
Out[385]: 
array([[[-2, -2, -2, -2],
        [-3, -3, -3, -3]],

       [[-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [-2, -2, -2, -2]]])
```

`norm` takes an `axis` parameter; specifying the last, gives the same result of doing the row-by-row calc with `vectorize`:

```
In [387]: np.linalg.norm(X[:,None,:]-Y[None,:,:], axis=-1)                                     
Out[387]: 
array([[4., 6.],
       [2., 4.]])
```

A downside to this properly 'vectorized' approach is that the broadcasted difference can get very large, and result in memory errors.

So `np.vectorize` is some-what useful when the function cannot use faster compiled whole-array methods.  But it isn't a speed-tool.  It's slower than a more explicit iteration.  The `signature` addition is interesting, but even slower.

`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` is a good tool for doing pair-wise distances.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, this helped a lot and gave me some new things that I can go and read up on! Thanks